# Deserialize steps in java

Tags: java, serialization

```
 class A extends Serializable{
      public A(){}
int x=0;
      private final transient ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    }
```

few Questions about deserialization:
1) Why is it required to provide default constructor in case serialization ?
2) Why field "lock" is not getting initialized after deserialization?

EDIT: forgot to add "transient" in my original post.Added it now.

Comment: `Serializable ` is an interface hence it should be `implements Serializable`

Comment: `2) Why field "lock" is not getting initialized after deserialization?` because it's transient.

Comment: @ EpicPandaForce, lock is not getting desrialized because of its transient nature. But why it is not getting "initialized" with a new object ? In actual I wanted to understand the steps of deserialization because of which it is not getting initialized?

Comment: I suggest you to read any java serialization tutorial to get a clear picture.

Coming to your questions:
 1) not at all required 
 2) As the lock variable is "**transient**", it is skipped while object of A gets serialized and when you de-serialize the lock variabl will be initialized to **null**.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Why is it required to provide default constructor in case serialization.

It isn't a requirement.  Or at least, it isn't a requirement if you use serialization as implemented using `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`.

> 2) Why field "lock" is not getting initialized after deserialization?

It should be initialized ... if you are using `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`.  The `lock` object should be serialized and then deserialized.

(If you have a case where `lock` apparently isn't being initialized, then please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to show what is happening.)

<sup>I incorrectly asserted that `ReentrantReadWriteLock` isn't serializable ... It is.</sup>

**UPDATE** in the version with `transient`.  The `lock` field for a deserialized instance of `A` will be `null`.  The initialization expression in the declaration of `lock` doesn't get executed.

For more information, please read the [Java Object Serialization Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html).

---

If you are using some other serialization mechanism, you need to say what it is.

Answer (score 1):

1. Not required
2. Lock gets initialized, below code does print the initialized lock(Just writing the Object of `B` in a byte array and reading back from it)

   ```
   public class B implements Serializable {
       private int x = 0;
       private final ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
           ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           try (ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)) {
                out.writeObject(new B());
           }
           catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               throw e;
           }
           byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

           ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
           try (ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis)) {
               B b = (B) in.readObject();
               System.out.println(b.lock);
           }
           catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               throw e;
           }
         }
      }
   }
   ```